# mysql GROUP BY date()

Tags: php, mysql

I want a to print something that looks like this:

date - kcal

2015/8/8 - 1700

2015/8/9 - 1785

2015/8/10 - 1822

So I want to group all records on the same date, but they are saved as timestamps in the database, so I need to convert them to just the date (no time) before grouping them, then sum up all kcal fields on the same date.

I'm having trouble getting my head around the syntax. This is what I have:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DATE(thedate), SUM(kcal) FROM food_records GROUP BY DATE(thedate) ORDER BY thedate");
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['thedate']. " - ". $row['SUM(kcal)'];
                echo "<br />";
            }
```

Here is my SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `food_records` (
 `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `thedate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `item_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `kcal` int(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here is SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"

protocol_version    10

version     5.1.73

version_comment     Source distribution

version_compile_machine     x86_64

version_compile_os  redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: And what problem did you encounter?

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in record.php on line 29

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated** (and will be removed in PHP7) and should not be used any more. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @Arjan maybe you can repeat it as a mantra, but this is not the OP problem. You are true with deprecated (in PHP 5.5), but if the OP is using PHP 5.4 or less is in right.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude but it is nothing wrong to inform the user about it. Especially because the OP calls `mysql_query` on the result of an `mysql_query` gives the impression that the OP might be new to using `mysql` in php , and if this is true it is a good idea to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` right from the beginning.

Comment: It's true, I don't say that it's incorrect. But I see all the morning the same comment and nothing to fix the OP problems.

Comment: @AdamUlivi just as a note: you should try to avoid to sort or group by a result of function like `DATE`. For smaller data sets it won't be a problem, but if the number of records grow, then those kind of queries will get really slow. If you realize that this is happening it might be better to add a column that only stores the date.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if OP is using PHP 5.4 or less, he should upgrade to the latest version. Also `mysqli` is available since PHP 5 and `PDO` since 5.1. Even if OP is using an older version of PHP, it's still good practice to avoid things that are deprecated in current versions. That is, of course, only valid if the replacement tool is available in the version that is being used.

Comment: I am according to you.